# Run a javascript injection via shell

Tags: javascript, shell, scripting

Is there a way to put a string like this into a shell script to run the javascript? I want to pipe it to `cURL` after the string is generated

`javascript:echo("some-site.org/get?id=JCqwurtdkcA&h="+info.h+"&r="+tstamp());`

Comment: Question is unclear. What tool do you use to run Javascript shell scripts? What are info and tstamp?

Comment: I don't have a tool. I don't know how to run js in shell at all. Info and tstamp are just functions on `some-site.org` that need to be executed to generate a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options for running javascript from the command-line. If you just want Javascript by itself, then [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is the popular option. For a full "browser" environment which is controlled by javascript on the command-line, try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: PhantomJS looks perfect. Dankje :)